# Updating DS918+ to DSM 6.2.3-25426 seems to have broken network connection

Tags: networking, synology

I updated to DSM 6.2.3-25426 last night and since then my DS918+ drops off the network after 30-60mins.  Sometimes I can ping it, sometimes not.  WebUI goes down, cannot even SSH.  Tried via LAN1 (connecting to local network) and LAN2 (laptop directly connected).

Only change is the DSM update.  The only thing that makes it respond again is powering off and back on.  Then it'll be good for another 30-60 minutes.  No idea where to even start looking for the problem.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synology support suggested I remove the additional 8Gb RAM I installed (taking total to 12Gb - Synology say only 8Gb is supported although the mobo/cpu support 16Gb).  The nas was previously stable with 12Gb for over a year.  I removed the extra anyway, and it was stable again.  So I used the Synology assistant to run a memory check first on just the 4Gb and then the 12GB and both were fine.  It's been stable ever since with the full 12 Gb, so no idea what the problem was.  May have been as simple as the memory needing to be re-seated I guess.